# 2 dimensional array in java error(prints with null)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, oop, dynamic-arrays

It prints with null values... How do I get rid of that? It gives me for example:

Present:

Leo null null null

I would like it to print nothing else but Leo if it doesn't reach 4.

Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Trial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] Student ={"Tom", "Jack", "Gio", "Leo"};
        String[][] Attendance = new String[4][4];



        System.out.println("STUDENT LIST-TAKE ATTENDANCE");

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            System.out.println("Type 1 for Present, 2 for Absent, 3 for Fieldtrip, or 4 for Late " + "for " + Student[i]);
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            double Att = scan1.nextDouble();

            int j = 0;

            if (Att == 1){
                Attendance[0][j] = Student[i];
                j++;
            }

            else if(Att == 2){
                Attendance[1][j] = Student[i];
                j++;
            }

            else if(Att == 3){
                Attendance[2][j] = Student[i];
                j++;
            }

            else if(Att == 4){
                Attendance[3][j] = Student[i];
                j++;
            }

            else
                System.out.println("Retry");

        }

        System.out.println("Present: ");
        for (int k = 0; k<=3; k++)
            System.out.print(Attendance[0][k] + "   ");
            System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Absent: ");
        for (int k = 0; k<=3; k++)
            System.out.print(Attendance[1][k] + "   ");
            System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Fieldtrip: ");
        for (int k = 0; k<=3; k++)
            System.out.print(Attendance[2][k] + "   ");
            System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Late: ");
        for (int k = 0; k<=3; k++)
            System.out.print(Attendance[3][k] + "   ");
            System.out.println();


        /*
        String[][] Attendance = {
            { "Present", },
            { "Absent",  },
            { "Fieldtrip", },
            { "Late",  }

        };


            System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < Attendance; i++) {
            System.out.print(Attendance[i][0] + ": ");
            for (int j = 1; j < Attendance[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(Attendance[i][j] + " ");
         }
         */

        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you can check whether it is null before printing.

Comment: A) read about java naming conventions - variable names go camelCase - always B) read about using floating point numbers. You basically never ever compare them using == directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use this as an example, you should be able to figure out the rest:

```
System.out.println("Present: ");
for (int k = 0; k<=3; k++)
    System.out.print(Attendance[0][k] + "   ");
System.out.println();
```

The problem you are having now is that things get printed even if they are null, so add a check before you print:

```
System.out.println("Present: ");
for (int k = 0; k<=3; k++) {
    if (Attendance[0][k] != null) {
        System.out.print(Attendance[0][k] + "   ");
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Now if you are certain that once you encounter a null value, every succeeding value is going to be null as well, you can just break out of the loop if such a condition is encountered:

```
System.out.println("Present: ");
for (int k = 0; k<=3; k++) {
    if (Attendance[0][k] != null) {
        System.out.print(Attendance[0][k] + "   ");
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: great! thanks. However, I have another issue. If all of my Students were present. So i would do: Tom-1, Jack,-1... so on then what I get is only the last one as they overlap. It prints: Present: Leo,  Absent,late and fieldtrip: null

Comment: @ronix_247_DOIT do the same changes to other blocks of code as well.

Comment: that only gets rid of the nulls if there is one name per column